# disable spurious "warning: left shift count >= width of type"

Tags: c++, gcc

I'm getting a spurious "warning: left shift count >= width of type" when compiling some template code with gcc:

```
template <int N> class bitval {
unsigned long  val;
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wall"
    const bitval &check() {
        if (N < sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT && val >= (1UL << N)) {
            std::clog << val << " out of range for " << N << " bits in " << std::endl;
            val &= (1UL << N) - 1; }
        return *this; }
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
};
```

The problem being that when it is instantiated with N == 64, it gives the warning.

Now the warning is completely spurious, as the code checks for N being large enough that no check/mask is needed, so when N is 64, the shifts will never happen.  But gcc warns anyways.  So I'm trying to disable the warning, but I can't figure out the needed #pragma magic to shut it up...

Comment: Clearly it's not spurious, the compiler knows more about the instantiation than you do. G++ is being nice and letting you know there is undefined behavior in your code. I would suggest using an `enable_if` to disable this template if `N` is greater than `63`

Comment: So you're just assuming that `unsigned long` is a 64-bit type? OK.

Comment: No, I don't think OP is assuming that (see `sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT` but I'm guessing the compiler doesn't realise that this means the `(1UL << N)` later in the `if` is "safe".

Comment: OP is not assuming anything of the sort. Anyway, I think the `val >= (1UL << N)` check is superfluous; the transformation will be a nop if `val < (1UL << N)`.

Comment: @Mgetz: But there's no undefined behaviour. The shifts are only evaluated if the first check for `N` succeeds, in which case they are in range and well defined - as the question describes.

Comment: @MikeSeymour clearly g++ has found a way.... so either it's a g++ bug... or the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mgetz: No, it's just a spurious warning, as the question says. The code presumably isn't analysed deeply enough to figure out that the undefined behaviour can't be triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag dispatching to the rescue:

```
const bitval& check() {
  constexpr bool enough_bits = (N < sizeof(unsigned long) * CHAR_BIT);
  using enough_bits_t = std::integral_constant<bool, enough_bits>;
  return check( enough_bits_t{} );
}
const bitval& check(std::false_type /*enough bits*/) {
  return *this;
} 
const bitval& check(std::true_type /*enough bits*/) {
  if (val >= (1UL << N)) {
    std::clog << val << " out of range for " << N << " bits in \n";
    val &= (1UL << N) - 1;
  }
  return *this;
}
```

The decision (are there enough bits) is a compile-time constant, so I calculate it as one.

I then build a type (`std::true_type` or `std::false_type`) based off that decision, and dispatch to one of two different overloads.

So the code where `N` is too big to be shifted that far is never instantiated, and hence no warning.  If there is a logic error in the decision, and the code is instantiated, I get a compiler warning instead of silence (had you managed to disable the warning, and you had a logic error, you'd get silent UB).